# Assign vector address to iterator

Tags: c++, vector

I'd like the vector iterator to point to a vector element.  I have

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
  std::vector<int> vec = {1,2,3,4,5};
  std::vector<int>::iterator it;

  // want "it" to point to the "3" element, so something like
  //   it = &prices[2];
  //   it = &prices.at(2);

}
```

but neither of these attempts work.  I guess I need some vector function that returns an iterator, instead of an address(?)

Comment: `it = vec.begin() + 2;`

Comment: Or `it = std::next(vec.begin(), 2);` Or the canonical answer - RTFM :-)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> neither of these attempts work

Indeed, you can't create a container iterator from a pointer to a container element. You can only get them from the container itself.

> I guess I need some vector function that returns an iterator

Yes, `begin()` returns an iterator to the first element. Increment that to refer to whichever element you want. For the third,

```
it = vec.begin() + 2;
```

or, more generally,

```
it = std::next(std::begin(container), 2);
```

which works even if the container isn't random-access.

Comment: Worth noting that `std::next` is only available in C++11, before that `it = container.begin(); std::advance(it, 2);` does the same thing - if just more awkward.

Answer (score 6):

The main way to get an iterator is to use one of:

```
std::vector<int>::begin()
std::vector<int>::end()
std::vector<int>::rbegin()
std::vector<int>::rend()
```

In your case:

```
std::vector<int> vec = {1,2,3,4,5};
std::vector<int>::iterator it = std::next(vec.begin(), 2);
```